Ubuntu 24.04, Nautilus won't start after "pkill" command
I have used a pkill command on an unresponsive Nautilus session: pkill nautilus. Now clicking on Nautilus icon in the dock does nothing, only explicit use of "nautilus" command in terminal re-opens it. However, after I reopen it from CLI, I can open new windows simply clicking on the icon.
Rebooting helps in a sense that the issue stops unless I use pkill on Nautilus again.
I'm not sure if it helps, but after upgrade to 24.04 I got quite a few issues with Nautilus:

After waking up from "Suspend" some icons as a bunch of red-blue pixels, while others seem intact. If I keep working it seems they go back to normal eventually.
Messed up icons alongside normal ones:




Dragging file I want to open into WPS office window to open it directly leaves a ghost icon on the screen that sits above any window I open. I killed Nautilus because of it in a first place, if I close/kill Nautilus this ghost icon disappears.




System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-11-05 16:40:05

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Lenovo ThinkStation P330
Memory:                                      32.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i7-8700K × 12
Graphics:                                    Quadro P4000
Disk Capacity:                               2.5 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            M1VKT21A
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-48-generic


Latest lines of sudo journalctl -b | grep -i error are:
Nov 05 16:26:35 Adi-Workstation kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] ERROR [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Nov 05 16:26:40 Adi-Workstation google-chrome.desktop[96364]: [96405:96411:1105/162640.809203:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
Nov 05 16:26:40 Adi-Workstation google-chrome.desktop[96364]: [96405:96411:1105/162640.813569:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
Nov 05 16:26:40 Adi-Workstation google-chrome.desktop[96364]: [96405:96411:1105/162640.817449:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
Nov 05 16:26:40 Adi-Workstation rstudio.desktop[99037]: [99037:1105/162640.827743:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
Nov 05 16:27:13 Adi-Workstation rstudio.desktop[99037]: [99037:1105/162713.155718:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
Nov 05 16:27:29 Adi-Workstation google-chrome.desktop[96364]: [96405:96411:1105/162729.164055:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
Nov 05 16:27:56 Adi-Workstation google-chrome.desktop[96364]: [96405:96411:1105/162756.075323:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
Nov 05 16:28:18 Adi-Workstation tracker-miner-fs-3[185260]: (tracker-extract-3:185260): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 16:28:18.975: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
Nov 05 16:29:14 Adi-Workstation rstudio.desktop[99037]: [99037:1105/162914.154962:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
Nov 05 16:29:37 Adi-Workstation google-chrome.desktop[96364]: [96405:96411:1105/162937.845593:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
Nov 05 16:29:40 Adi-Workstation google-chrome.desktop[96364]: [96405:96411:1105/162940.120419:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
Nov 05 16:31:39 Adi-Workstation gvfsd-network[98543]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: Failed to spawn the underlying wsdd daemon.
Nov 05 16:31:39 Adi-Workstation gvfsd-network[98543]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: mountpoint for org.gtk.vfs.mountpoint_wsdd already running
Nov 05 16:32:53 Adi-Workstation tracker-miner-fs-3[185482]: (tracker-extract-3:185482): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 16:32:53.966: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
Nov 05 16:33:32 Adi-Workstation google-chrome.desktop[96364]: [96405:96411:1105/163332.353942:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
Nov 05 16:35:00 Adi-Workstation gvfsd-network[98543]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: Failed to spawn the underlying wsdd daemon.
Nov 05 16:35:00 Adi-Workstation gvfsd-network[98543]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: mountpoint for org.gtk.vfs.mountpoint_wsdd already running
Nov 05 16:36:23 Adi-Workstation google-chrome.desktop[96364]: [185660:20:1105/163623.936430:ERROR:ffmpeg_common.cc(970)] Unsupported pixel format: -1
Nov 05 16:38:12 Adi-Workstation google-chrome.desktop[96364]: [185740:19:1105/163812.671024:ERROR:ffmpeg_common.cc(970)] Unsupported pixel format: -1
Nov 05 16:38:12 Adi-Workstation google-chrome.desktop[96364]: [185740:19:1105/163812.790444:ERROR:ffmpeg_common.cc(970)] Unsupported pixel format: -1
Nov 05 16:38:48 Adi-Workstation gvfsd-network[98543]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: Failed to spawn the underlying wsdd daemon.
Nov 05 16:38:48 Adi-Workstation gvfsd-network[98543]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: mountpoint for org.gtk.vfs.mountpoint_wsdd already running

Without knowing what processes you killed it is difficult to help with specific instructions. Can you tell us the exact pkill command you used? Does the problem persist when you reboot the system? Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification.

I will edit the description.
